# To print data to a file

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have overloaded `<<` operator such that it write to file and also on the console. I have created 8 threads to the same function, and I want to output

```
 hello
  hi
```

If I run this thread routine in an infinite loop the o/p in the file is

hello

hi

hello

hi

hello

hi

ello

i

hello

hi

hello

hi

llo

i

hello

hi

This has no pattern. What is the problem? I am able to print it properly on console but not into a file.

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: If you just naively create several threads and start them spewing output, there aren't any guarantees about the order of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a queue and write to it.  Dequeue queue in desired granularity - one line for example (I guess that that's what you want from your example).

Something like:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
list<string> _queue;
void Write(string line) 
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    _queue.push_back(line); 
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}
ThreadProc()
{
    while (!_shouldStop)
    {
        Dequeue();
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
void Dequeue()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    if (!_queueIsEmpty()) 
    {
         string line=_queue.front(); 
         _queue.pop_front();
         stream << line;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}
```

This is not C code - this is just a example, there are lot's of other things to have in mind, just to name few of them:

- your granularity might vary, I used line here
- you might want to use dequeue<> or some similar FIFO structure
- you might want to `WaitForSingleObject()` instead of `Sleep()`-ing to have better control for cases when you want to stop
- create singleton object for the stuff and use it where you need it (I guess that you are creating some kind of logging facility?)

Comment: for the love of god, can you comment instead of -1-ing me?

Comment: Not my -1, but well deserved. Sleep(100)? Thread safety? Buffer overflow? Unprotected access of a shared variable? There are plenty of reasons to downvote this.

Comment: I addressed all of that issues in the comments.  Variable access: critical section. Sleep - use WaitForSingleObject.  Hm...

Comment: MSalters, if you agree to downvote because of a Sleep(), you can downvote for not providing a DVD with a setup.exe too. Daniel hit the bull's eye of the problem. I guess you would downvote for not mentioning the InitializeCriticalSection and DeleteCriticalSection too...

Answer (score 4):

Are you locking a mutex when you are sending data to a stream? The c++ stream classes are not thread-safe.

Comment: when i lock it using a mutex...the o/p is proper...why do i get this prob if i dont lock it with mutex???

Comment: @Manu:  Why do you consider this a "problem?"

Comment: You started 8 threads doing the same thing.  They are all doing the same thing at the same time.  Why would you expect anything other than what you see?

Comment: @John I think he is just printing that message in 8 threads to a standard output.

Comment: @Manu Because most c++03 classes are not thread safe. Now that I think of it, is there a c++03 class that is thread safe?

Comment: @VJo: C++03 leaves threads to the implementations; you'd have to discuss whether a class in a particular implementation is thread-safe. That said, the most common answer is yes, they're all as threadsafe as an int. Meaning you _still_ need a mutex if you modify one object from two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a problem of synchronization between thread.

For example with 2 thread: (cout of a string is representing by "print" character).

```
thread1  thread2
print h
print e 
print l
         print h
print l
print o
         print e

print \n
         print l
         print l
         print o
         print \n
```

the result will be:

```
helhloe
llo
```

you need to make sure that your function is not used by two thread at the same time.

```
function_cout_hello()
  lock()
  file << ...
  unlock()
```

like that, two different thread can not use the function at the same time.

Comment: That's a bit over the top. `ostream` is used for formatted output. Formatting can be done in parallel on each thread; you only need to synchronize the output part.

Comment: @MSalters: Thats a nice point. But I do agree with you but you still need to be carefull on a few thing. the manipulator std::endl will flush the content of the osteam buffer which need to be locked (or you need to control manually when the buffer content will be flushed in the file)